# attaching Costmap2DROS object to existing costmaps (i.e. from movebase)

Tags: navigation, costmap, costmap-2d-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all. I think i'm finally on the right track to solving my problem. If you would like to see the original problem, I asked about it here http://answers.ros.org/question/190858/how-to-go-about-this-engineering-problem-using-navigation-stack/ -- still no responses though :(

I should be able to set up individual layers using specific sensors similar to what is described here: http://answers.ros.org/question/83471/layered-costmap-problem/

Ultimately, I'm going to set up 2 static layers, and I need to save the map generated by one of these static layer and I will load it next time the navigation stack runs.

I think the way of doing this is by using accessing the Costmap2DROS C++ object detailed here: http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d

Looking at the API, it makes sense that I would be able to create a new one of these objects in a .cpp file, but I don't know how I would go about getting the Costmap2DROS objects that move_base creates when it is launched.

Does anyone have any idea as to how to obtain a C++ interface to the global and local costmaps that move_base instantiates when you run similar launch files to what is on the tutorials? Maybe you can create the object with a parameter such as the topic or node name or something.

Thanks if anyone can help.

Also, i'm on indigo so maybe the Costmap2DROS object is not called that anymore.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191620/attaching-costmap2dros-object-to-existing-costmaps-(i.e.-from-movebase)/) by [Garrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/12401/garrick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2014-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps this is beside the point, but have you tried http://wiki.ros.org/map_server#map_saver?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Garrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/12401/garrick/) on 2014-09-01**:
Thanks for the reply David.
The thing is I'm going to be running 2 static layers, but I need to save and initialize only one of these. I can't save and initialize the superposition of them (i.e the costmap topic). Is there are way to use map_saver to save an inividual layer? If so this is fine.

**Comment by [Garrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/12401/garrick/) on 2014-09-01**:
I know you can initialize from a static map here: http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/staticmap
But that would require being able to save the map generated from the individual static layer. Can you do this? I could maybe just create another costmap_2d with just the 1 static layer, then use that.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-09-03**:
Right now, there is not a method for saving an individual layer. You can dynamically disable some of the layers, through dynamic_reconfigure, and then save the whole costmap. If you think its important, add a ticket for publishing individual layers.